# I have created a connection inside the constructor, but I am having errors upon saving the component

Tags: mysql, reactjs, connection

I have properly imported mysql.
Here is my code wherein I declared the connection inside the constructor.

```
import mysql from 'mysql';
export class StepForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state ={
            step: 1, 
            // welcome
            qNumber:1,
            accountNumber:'',
            amount:'',
            txNumber:1,
            postArray : []
        }
        const connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 3306,
            user: 'root',
            password: 'whil',
            database: 'qany'
        });
        connection.connect();
        console.log(connection);
    }
```

upon saving the component I encountered error,

```
TypeError: Net.createConnection is not a function
Connection.connect
C:/react_programs/q_any/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:74
  71 | this._connectCalled = true;
  72 | 
  73 | // Connect either via a UNIX domain socket or a TCP socket.
> 74 | this._socket = (this.config.socketPath)
     | ^  75 |   ? Net.createConnection(this.config.socketPath)
  76 |   : Net.createConnection(this.config.port, this.config.host);
  77 |
```

what should be done?